# DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer - Dead-letter publication failed with InvalidTopicException for name topic at TopicPartition ends with _ERR

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I identified an error when I changed the DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer destionationResolver.

When I use:

```
private static final BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, TopicPartition>
        DESTINATION_RESOLVER = (cr, e) -> new TopicPartition(cr.topic() + ".ERR", cr.partition());
```

it works perfectly.

However, if you use _ERR instead of .ERR, an error occurs:

```
2020-08-05 12:53:10,277 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-kafka-tx-group1.ABC_TEST_XPTO.0] WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-kafka-tx-group1.ABC_TEST_XPTO.0, transactionalId=kafka-tx-group1.ABC_TEST_XPTO.0] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 7 : {ABC_TEST_XPTO_ERR=INVALID_TOPIC_EXCEPTION}
```

2020-08-05 12:53:10,278 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-kafka-tx-group1.ABC_TEST_XPTO.0] ERROR org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-kafka-tx-group1.ABC_TEST_XPTO.0, transactionalId=kafka-tx-group1.ABC_TEST_XPTO.0] Metadata response reported invalid topics [ABC_TEST_XPTO_ERR]
2020-08-05 12:53:10,309 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener - Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='XPTOEvent(super=Event(id=CAPBA2548, destination=ABC_TEST_XPTO, he...' to topic ABC_TEST_XPTO_ERR and partition 0:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: Invalid topics: [ABC_TEST_XPTO_ERR]
2020-08-05 12:53:10,320 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] ERROR o.s.k.l.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer - Dead-letter publication failed for: ProducerRecord(topic=ABC_TEST_XPTO_ERR, partition=0, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = ..
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: Invalid topics: [ABC_TEST_XPTO_ERR]
at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:573)
at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:388)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.publish(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:290)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:226)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:54)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.FailedRecordTracker.skip(FailedRecordTracker.java:106)
strong text

**My topics use _ in the middle of the name, for example ABC_TEST_XPTO, so I would like to set up the dead letter topic with _ERR, if possible**

My enviroment

1. Spring Boot  2.3.2.RELEASE
2. Spring-Kafka 2.5.3.RELEASE but the same problem occurs with 2.5.4.RELEASE
3. Java 11

   private static final BiFunction<ConsumerRecord, Exception, TopicPartition>
   DESTINATION_RESOLVER = (cr, e) -> new TopicPartition(cr.topic() + "_ERR", cr.partition());

   @Component
   class ContainerFactoryConfigurer {

   ```
   ContainerFactoryConfigurer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory,
                              ChainedKafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> tm,
                              KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {

       factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(tm);
       DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor rollbackProcessor = new DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor((record, exception) -> {
       }, new FixedBackOff(0L, Long.valueOf(maxAttemps)), template, true);
       factory.setAfterRollbackProcessor(rollbackProcessor);
       SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
               new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(Collections.singletonMap(Object.class, template), DESTINATION_RESOLVER), new FixedBackOff(0L, Long.valueOf(maxAttemps)));
       errorHandler.setCommitRecovered(true);
       errorHandler.setAckAfterHandle(true);
       factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
   }
   ```

   }

Thanks
DPG

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63270367Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63270367Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("ABC_TEST_XPTO_ERR").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> template.send("ABC_TEST_XPTO_ERR", "foo");
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so63270367", topics = "ABC_TEST_XPTO_ERR")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

Maybe your brokers have some rules about topic names; maybe look at the broker logs?

**EDIT**

As I said in my comment; it shouldn't matter where the record is published from; this still works for me...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63270367Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63270367Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("ABC_TEST_XPTO").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topicErr() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("ABC_TEST_XPTO_ERR").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> template.send("ABC_TEST_XPTO_ERR", "foo");
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so63270367", topics = "ABC_TEST_XPTO")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so63270367err", topics = "ABC_TEST_XPTO_ERR")
    public void listenErr(String in) {
        System.out.println("From DLT:" + in);
    }

    @Bean
    public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler eh(KafkaOperations<String, String> template) {
        return new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(
                template,
                (cr, e) -> new TopicPartition(cr.topic() + "_ERR", cr.partition())),
                new FixedBackOff(0L, 0L));
    }

}
```

```
From DLT:foo
```

Comment: Hi Gary,

Thank you for the quick answer.
Yes, I have no problem creating a topic with _ in the name. The problem happens when an exception occurs in the consumption of this topic and having configured SeekToCurrentErrorHandler with DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer and customized the destionationResolver

Comment: I don't see where the record is published from would make a difference; but I'll test it.

Comment: I just completed my configuration on my question. And yes, I'm setting spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset = earliest.

The strangest thing is that if I set up destionationResolver to concatenate .ERR to the topic name it works, but if using _ERR does not

Once more, thank you

Comment: It still works fine for me; see my edit. There must be something else going on. If you can provide a small example like mine that reproduces the issue, I can take a look.