# Unable to send messages to dead letter topic from consumer in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

'I am trying to route a message to a Dead letter topic in Kafka in case of any failures in processing the corresponding message. I have setup the SeektoCurrentErrorHandler and DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer for this functionality.

The consumer throws the following exception while doing this:

```
2020-08-07 12:09:38.841 ERROR 1 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='a6558a22-470d-4708-b297-814996a42045' and payload='{123, 34, 101, 118, 101, 110, 116, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58, 34, 116, 101, 115, 116, 95, 101, 120, 1...' to topic test_execution.DLT and partition 2:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test_execution.DLT not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

2020-08-07 12:09:38.846 ERROR 1 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer    : Dead-letter publication failed for: ProducerRecord(topic=test_execution.DLT, partition=2, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-topic, value = [116, 101, 115, 116, 95, 101, 120, 101, 99, 117, 116, 105, 111, 110]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-partition, value = [0, 0, 0, 2]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-offset, value = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 15, -72]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-timestamp, value = [0, 0, 1, 115, -57, 103, -70, -126]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-timestamp-type, value = [67, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 84, 105, 109, 101]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-exception-fqcn, value = [111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 69, 120, 101, 99, 117, 116, 105, 111, 110, 70, 97, 105, 108, 101, 100, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-exception-message, value = [    
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test_execution.DLT not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:570) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:385) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.publish(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:278) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:214) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:54) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.FailedRecordProcessor.getSkipPredicate(FailedRecordProcessor.java:167) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:104) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1887) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1792) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1719) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1617) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1348) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1064) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:972) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test_execution.DLT not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

I have already created the test_execution.DLT topic in the kafka cluster and I am clearly able to produce messages to this topic from the consoler-producer.

The consumer is running inside a docker container and the kafka cluster is a 3 VM setup.
These are the configs used by the kafka consumer:

```
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
        props.put("spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class", StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put("spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class", JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 10);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        return props;
    }
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(),  new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(new StringDeserializer()),
                new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(new JsonDeserializer<>(AutomationEvent.class,false)));
    }

    @Bean
    public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler(KafkaOperations kafkaOperations) {
        return new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaOperations), new FixedBackOff(10000, 3));
    }
```

Am I missing something here? Do I need to modify any server configuration for this to be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you also specify the producer configuration if you want to send messages to topics from the consumers. The property for this is `spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers`

This property is necessary or else the producer component tries to connect to locahost by default, which leads to no topics found.

Comment: I have a topic problem. Here is my project : https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootkafka

Answer (score 3):

> test_execution.DLT not present

The framework does not automatically create the dead letter topic for you; it has to exist already.

You can instruct the framework to create the topic by adding a `NewTopic` `@Bean`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63270367/deadletterpublishingrecoverer-dead-letter-publication-failed-with-invalidtopic/63270883#63270883) for an example.

**EDIT**

By default, we will send the record to the same partition so the DLT must have at least as many partitions as the original topic, unless you supply a destination resolver.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#dead-letters).

> By default, the dead-letter record is sent to a topic named .DLT (the original topic name suffixed with .DLT) and to the same partition as the original record. Therefore, when you use the default resolver, the dead-letter topic must have at least as many partitions as the original topic. If the returned TopicPartition has a negative partition, the partition is not set in the ProducerRecord, so the partition is selected by Kafka.

Comment: I have explicitly created the dead letter topic outside of the consumer. Also sent a few test messages to the topic from a console producer. 
What does this NewTopic Bean represent? Does this mean we have to explicity provide the NewTopic bean for every DLT topic even though it is already created in the kafka cluster?

Comment: You probably don't have enough partitions in the DLT - see the edit. The `NewTopic` bean can set or increase the partitions or you can increase them with the command line tools.

Comment: I have crosschecked the partitions and replication factor count of all the DLT topics with their main counterparts. The partitions and replication factor counts are exactly the same (3 each). 
I don't want to set the NewTopic bean for DLT topics in the consumer as I have already created them in the cluster.
Is this information/metadata not getting through to the consumer?

Comment: You don't need the `NewTopic` bean if the topic already exists and has enough partitions. It has nothing to do with the runtime, it is just used to provision the topic during startup. If it has enough topics and you are still getting this error, it makes no sense to me.

Comment: I just tested it myself; sent a record to partition 2 of a 3 partition topic with the .DLT only having one partition and I got the exact same result as you (as I expected). I then increased the DLT partitions to 3 and it worked just fine.

Comment: After busting my head on this, I finally figured it out. I never really specified the producer configs in the application.
So the producer component of the consumer was trying to connect to localhost by default!
Adding the producer configs did the trick. Learnt the lesson the hard way!
Thank you so much for helping me with this.

Comment: Thank you for the tip of the same number of partitions. That was the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Consumer does not have to send any information to DLT, it is handled by the framework, only that the topic has to exist before

Follow this discussion -> [DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer - Dead-letter publication failed with InvalidTopicException for name topic at TopicPartition ends with _ERR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63270367/deadletterpublishingrecoverer-dead-letter-publication-failed-with-invalidtopic/63270883#63270883)